# xcode error message when l wanted to run ios app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

dyld abort_abort_with_payload was show immediately when l click on the run button in xcode.The build was successful but l couldn't run it on a simulator.l recently download the latest version of xcode to stay up to date and l was unable to run my app in a simulator.

Please l need help on how to properly configure the build settings to run a cordova ios project on an iphone 7 plus simulator without errors. Thank you

Comment: Usually when you get that error message if you look in the console you'll find the name of a framework/library which didn't load. Click on your target and make sure that library appears in the section called "Embedded Binaries". If it doesn't drag it there, or click on the '+' to add it.

Comment: my console is showing dyld: dyld_sim is not compatible with the loaded process, likely due to architechture mismatch. l couldn't find the name of the framework/library which didn't load. The Embedded Binaries is currently empty. l don't know which one to add

Comment: You'll need help from someone who uses Cordova, I guess. Since the message indicates that one of your frameworks is missing an architecture, that means it might have been compiled for the device, but not simulator, or vice versa. Typically you need both eventually. I expect someone will be able to help you.